# How do I install Ubuntu 22.04 on my Laptop which already has Windows 10 installed

Tags: system-installation

I no longer want windows on this HP Laptop. I have bought the Ubuntu DVD from the Linux Shop, but I am unsure of the installation procedure. I know this sounds a bit juvenile but I am brand new to Linux and would be grateful for some help please.

---

@HomerSimpson I thank you for your reply, however my knowledge of open source is almost non existent. I don't know what the live environment is. I bought Ubuntu DVD and thought that all I had to do was put it in the cd player and it would automatically boot up like windows. If you could explain the live environment to me. I will certainly give it a go before trying anything else.

Comment: Booting to the DVD and using "Try Ubuntu" is going to get you to the LIve Environment.  "Install Ubuntu" should be an option on the desktop to install Ubuntu and then that's where Homer's answer comes into place.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try `Ubuntu` in the `live environment` first. So you can explore the system and see if all your hardware is functioning. Also look at what software you used in `Windows` and if there is an alternative for `Linux systems`. If everything works you can make your `Windows partition` smaller and install `Ubuntu`. You can install it next to `Windows`. Do not wipe your `Windows installation` yet. The learning curve is pretty steep as it uses other software/programs than `Windows`. If it is a second laptop (not your daily driver) you can format the partition(s) and install it on the whole disk. For more information about installing Ubuntu see https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview. I am not trying to talk you out of it, I just don't want you to jump of a ship before you learned how to swim.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the cd in the cd-drive you can boot on ubuntu (using the computer's bios/uefi) .
From here the live-CD answers you what you want to do, and you can select " try ubuntu ": if you select this option you will be able to try ubuntu without installing it (that is the live environment) and verify if everything works fine for you and your hardware. If that is the case you can install it . During the installation you can choose if you want to keep windows or not (see the link in previous answers).